# Javascript checking event handler in element

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have p tag without any attr. I added two events to p tag. In console I can get events with `getEventListeners()` function, but I don't want that. In my code I check if p has event then console "yes", but I don't know which event it is. How can I detect event? I want name of event click or `mouseover`.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat nam mollitia officiis deleniti quae quos. Nulla voluptate, quibusdam dolor vero sed voluptatum, incidunt eum dicta, iste beatae animi inventore repudiandae.</p>

p[0].addEventListener("click",function () {
    /* body... */
    p[0].style.color="green";
    p[0].style.fontSize="24px";
})

p[0].addEventListener("mouseover",function () {
    /* body... */
    p[0].style.color="red";
    p[0].style.fontSize="12px";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

JS doesn't quite do that, and getEventListeners() isn't quite well supported.
Some libraries keep a list of them but then they wouldn't know about events attached by other means (i.e. vanilla js).
The only way seems to be if you create a wrapper around addEventListener and use that to cache whatever it's being on something.

You could (but please don't) do something like this (not tested, not sure if working):

```
Element.prototype.setEvent = function(eventName, eventAction) {
    this.eventList = this.eventList || [];

    this.addEventListener(eventName, eventAction);
    this.eventList.push(eventName);
};
```

Then you could use setEvent instead of addEventListener and you can access a list of event listeners from .eventList.

Modifying objects (such as `Element.prototype`) is an anti-pattern though, so I do not recommend it.

A better thing to do would be

```
/**
 * Adds an event to elements matching a selector, then saves them in a data attribute.
 * @param {String} elements - the selector (e.g. 'p')
 * @param {String} eventName - the event (e.g. 'click')
 * @param {Function} eventAction - the function to invoke when the event occurs
 */
writeSearchableEvent = function(elements, eventName, eventAction) {
    elements = document.querySelectorAll(elements);

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var eventData = {
            event: eventName,
            action: eventAction
        };

        elements[i].addEventListener(eventName, eventAction);
        elements[i].setAttribute('data-attached-events', eventData);
    }
};
```

Of course you would need to modify how the data attribute is handled but hopefully this could give you an idea.

Comment: cahce? can you explain how?